# iptables Port Forwarding Not Working

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, iptables

I have a server that I configured to be a router (Debian 7 Stable). eth0 is hooked up to my cable modem, and eth1 is hooked up to a 24-port switch. DHCP,DNS,Routing,Traffic all work fine. The only thing I can't seem to get working is port forwarding. I want to forward traffic from port 65010 to 172.16.254.10, but it times out. Below is the script that I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
# init

## Flush current configuration:
iptables -F
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t mangle -F

## Delete current chains:
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -X

## Set policy
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

## Allow routing between eth0 and eth1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT

## Allow internal SSH:
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.254.0/24 -m state --state NEW \
        -p tcp -m multiport --dports 65001,65010 -j ACCEPT

## Allow external SSH:
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 65001,65010 -j ACCEPT

## Allow port forwarding for SSH:
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 65010 \
                      -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.254.10

## Required for internal host name resolution to function:
iptables -I INPUT -s 172.16.254.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 172.16.254.0/24 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

## Required for Samba to function:
iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.254.0/24 -m state --state NEW -p tcp \
                   -m multiport --dports 137,138,139,445 -j ACCEPT

iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules
```

Comment: is `net.ipv4.ip_forward` set to `1`? what is the output of `iptables -Lvn`? You could make this quesdtion easier to read by removing the lines from your iptables settings which obviously does not affect port forwarding in any way (like `iptables -A INPUT -s 172.16.254.0/24 -m state --state NEW -p tcp -m multiport --dports 137,138,139,445 -j ACCEPT`or `iptables-save > /etc/iptables.rules`

Comment: Yes, net.ipv4.ip_forward is set to 1. The output of iptables -Lvn is: "No chain/target/match by that name." I included the entire script because for all I know, anything on there could be stopping it.

Comment: I see the rule that performs the nat, but where is the rule that actually permits the traffic?   A rule on the nat table will modify the packet, but that does not imply the packet will actually be accepted/forwarded.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the following should be allowing it, shouldn't it: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 65001,65010 -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 65010 -d 172.16.254.10 -j ACCEPT
```

On the other hand, you are not setting any default policies to DROP nor added any "-j DROP" rules in any chains to catch unmatched traffic, so everything is permitted.

Lastly you might want to add the destination's port number in the DNAT rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 65010 -j DNAT \
                                --to-destination 172.16.254.10:65010
```

Try running something like tcpdump or wireshark to make sure that packets are forwarded properly to the internal destination.

Comment: Thanks. You say that I'm not setting any default policies therefore everything is permitted, but if that is the case, then why am I not able to access anything at all until I allow it? For example, just now I realized that I cannot ping internal machines so I'm trying to figure out what firewall will allow internal ping (but not allow pinging from the WAN).

Comment: iptables -S && iptables -nvxL will let you know what is the default policy. Possibly you run this script after something else already set the default policies to "DROP"

Comment: I ran the commands: http://pastebin.com/JsuyBeAh 
Should I be concerned or change anything in my policy?